# Como comprimir archivos pdf que estoy generando con Django y xhtml2pdf?

Tags: python, django, pdf, zip, xhtml2pdf

Estoy generando unos reportes en PDF de una base de datos SQL con la librería XHTML2PDF. El problema, son muchos y aún debo generar los PDF individualmente, me gustaría una forma de usar la función de generar PDF para comprimirlos en un .ZIP y así solo descargar un archivo, o mandarlo por correo.
**Mi vista:**

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
#from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

def link_callback(uri, rel):
  """
  Convert HTML URIs to absolute system paths so xhtml2pdf can access those
  resources
  """
  result = finders.find(uri)
  if result:
    if not isinstance(result, (list, tuple)):
      result = [result]
    result = list(os.path.realpath(path) for path in result)
    path=result[0]
  else:
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL        # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT      # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL         # Typically /media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT       # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
      path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
      path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
      return uri

  # make sure that file exists
  if not os.path.isfile(path):
    raise Exception(
      'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl)
    )
  return path


def render_pdf_view(request):
  template_path = 'base_pdf.html'
  context = {'myvar': 'this is your template context'}
  # Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf
  response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'
  # find the template and render it.
  template = get_template(template_path)
  html = template.render(context)

  # create a pdf
  pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
    html, dest=response)
    # , link_callback=link_callback
  # if error then show some funy view
  if pisa_status.err:
    return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
  return response
```

aún no lo tengo conectado a la base de datos, por eso no estoy usando la función link_callback

Gracias por el tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### solución

pego solo el codigo de la funcion que renderiza. Añada los imports:

```
import zipfile
import io
```

código:

```
def render_pdf_view(request):
    template_path = 'base_pdf.html'
    context = {'myvar': 'this is your template context'}
    # Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.zip"'
    # find the template and render it.
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)

    # virtual in-memmory file, beautifull but dangerous too!
    pdf_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # crender PDF to pdf_buffer
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
        html, dest=pdf_buffer)
    # if error then show some funy view
    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')

    # zip pdf_buffer to zip_buffer
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zip_file:
        zip_file.writestr('name_fichero.pdf', pdf_buffer.getvalue())
    # put data to response object
    response.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())

    return response
```

#### explicaciones

Genial ejercicio de aprendizaje y manejo de los conceptos [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) and [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) !

La arquitectura que estas utilizando es ideal en un contexto de aprendizaje, pero no en un sistema de producción o con muchos usuarios.

He escogido la versión de escribirlo en ficheros en memoria, si quieres escribirlos en el servidor, solo tienes que añadir:

```
with open('file.pdf','w') as file:
    file.write(pdf_buffer.getvalue())
with open('file.zip','w') as file:
    file.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())
```

En caso de necesidad de elevar en producción este sistema hay que separar los trabajos de renderización,acceso/escritura de ficheros - de los de request-response web.  Lo dejamos para otras preguntas!

Comment: que pena, no habia podido probar bien esta solucion, ahora que lo he intentado, me sale un error: write() argument must be str, not bytes. esto pasa al momento de pasar pdf_buffer.getvalue() a la funcion write().

Comment: Estoy casi convencido que lo prove, lastima de no poner el output...  EI metodo .getValue() de BytesIO devuelve bytes, y  método write de file objects acepta 
bytes, no veo logica en tu error